# how to get long life access_token using curl?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

How to get long life access_token using curl and store in variable ?

My web host unable to use file_get_contents() due to some reasons thats why i am unable to use this so that next option is available for me is to use CUrl i known about that and learn but i didn't understand.

below is the url which we use to get long life access_token note i already store access_token in $atoken

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="id"&client_secret="its seceret ;)"&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=$atoken
```

Thanks

Comment: "How to get long life access_token using curl and store in variable" --- any **real reason** for that? It is possible to do anything you want with temporary tokens

Comment: actually i want that my wall updates automatically using my fb app and after 50 days my computer automatically open update.php file so that its update the long life access token automatically 2 so that my app updates my wall automatically and dosent need any user interaction

Comment: posting to the wall doesn't require any user interactions and permanent tokens. You can post using regular (temporary) tokens

Comment: temp tokens expires after almost 2 hours

Comment: yes. so? You retrieve new token and then post message to the wall. It takes several seconds. So 2 hours is a really great deal, isn't it? After a week when you need to post another message - you retrieve another token and post another message.

Comment: sorry for late reply actually i didn't see your comment 
no actually i want to post message daily automatically my app run daily using cron jobs and maybe i set this after 50 days a automatically my computer start and visit facebook.com than its visit the update.php file so that its update the long life acces_token on my database and than computer close after few minutes

Comment: as I said twice - you don't need long life tokens for that. It is the third time: you can do that with regular tokens. I have no idea why you think you need long-lived tokens, but I'm too bored to repeat the same thing more and more. And for the last time: you can post whatever whenever you want using short-lived tokens.

Comment: @zerkms i didn't understand how is it possible that i run a file using cron jobs and is get the user token is it possible ?

Comment: as long as user gave the permission to post to his wall - you can do that whenever you want, without any additional long-live tokens.

Comment: 1.offline access is deprecated 
2.temp token valid for only two hours 
3.cron job not able to get user access_token because there is no user login in server 
so see this for example 
i setup a database with 100 posts data which my app use to post on my wall daily using cron jobs and use update.php in eaach 50 days and on first time to get temp token than get long life token because normal token expires in almost 2 hours and because my app is run with cron jobs so there is no user interaction so that my app not able to get user access_token but if my app have long life access_token (see on 2 c)

Comment: than its able to post on user and its dosent need any user interaction in 50 days

Comment: "cron job not able to get user access_token because there is no user login in server" --- I said already 3 times, that you don't need that, because user ALREADY PERMITTED YOU TO WRITE POSTS ON THEIR WALL. How much should I say else for you to understand - that you **CAN DO THAT WITH TEMPORARY TOKENS**? When you need to post a message to the wall - you retrieve **NEW TEMPORARY TOKEN** and use it.

Comment: Please read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms about `publish_stream` permission, because what you said is just incorrect

Comment: And perhaps I will say that for the 5 time: you don't need any user interaction even after 100 years and even if you use temporary tokens. That is what `publish_stream` permission for

Answer (score 1):

Make simple cURL request like that

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="id"&client_secret="its  seceret ;)"&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=$atoken';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "I-am-browser");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
```

Comment: i got the following error 

Call to undefined function url_close()

Comment: ok i correct url = curl 

than got the following errors when i echo the $ch and $response 

























array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(27) "Invalid OAuth access token." ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(190) } } ch: Resource id #3response: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}

Comment: i didn't understand why you said look at this link well i visit the page and read it partly my app is simply gets the temporary token but when trying to get the long life access_token using curl its show the above error

Comment: but i echo the token and its correct and i also try to get the long life token manually and got the success and i got the success but the problem is that i want to do this automatically

Comment: visit the url and check directly 

https://apps.facebook.com/hack-proof_pages/llc.php

Comment: and please note my app use self signed certificate ssl so if you visit this url you have to store its certificate and allow this site

Comment: i found here is maybe a problem in your above curl usage because i tried this that i write the complete url means also include my current access_token than its show "null" in response and when i copy paste the $url in address bar its show the long life access token